# the firebase getValue method is not retrieving the value from the node as it should

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase database I have a node that has children that hold the latitude and longitude of a location like so in the json snippet below

```
{
  "DriversAvailable" : {
    "sfdqfkoxYjXB2YRDTfIaezWgkBd2" : {
      ".priority" : "dn5bpxwrtz",
      "g" : "dn5bpxwrtz",
      "l" : [ 33.7925271, -84.3881384 ]
    }
```

and I am using the following code to place the latitude and longitude into seperate variables

```java
driverLocationReferenceGetLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable").child(driverFoundID);
driverLocationReferenceGetLocation.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             Double latitude = (Double) snapm.child("0").getValue();
             Double longitude = (Double) snapm.child("1").getValue();
```

When i debug this it shows that the value snapm has the value set 1={0=33.79, 1=-84.38}, but for some reason  the actual latitude and longitude variables are null

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's not working in your code, but I'd definitely recommend listening to the precise node whose data you're trying to get:

```
driverLocationReferenceGetLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable").child(driverFoundID);
driverLocationReferenceGetLocation.child("l").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Double latitude = snapshot.child("0").getValue(Double.class);
        Double longitude = snapshot.child("1").getValue(Double.class);
```